# PostgreSQL Insert not working without Error

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to update my table by comparing it with another table and add the missing rows. I trired a bunch of similar posts here but nothing helped.

This is the productdetails table (main table)

| Name | Price | Availability | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5.5 | yes | ... |
| B | 7.2 | no | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

This is the pdtemporary table (temp table)

| Name | Price | Availability | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5.5 | yes | ... |
| C | 6.8 | no | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

No I want to add all rows from the temp tble to the maintable which have a other name.

| Name | Price | Availability | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5.5 | yes | ... |
| B | 7.2 | no | ... |
| C | 6.8 | no | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I tried the following code:

```
INSERT INTO productdetails (name, price, availability)

(SELECT name, price, availability
                   
FROM pdtemporary
WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM pdtemporary ));
```

or

```
INSERT INTO productdetails (name, price, availability)

SELECT t2.name, t2.price, t2.availability
                   
FROM pdtemporary t2
where name != t2.name ;
```

And the Output is always

```
INSERT 0 0

Query returned successfully in xxx msec.
```

select * from -> also testet and not working.

have I forgotten something trivial or is "INSERT" not the right way in this case?
The table has about 60,000 - 120,000 rows and about 20 columns.

Comment: Example one fails as `WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM pdtemporary )` is asking for `pdtemporary.name NOT IN pdtemporary.name` which is going to yield 0 rows. Example two fails because `name != t2.name` will also yield 0 as I'm pretty sure there is a`B` row in the temporary table and there is no `C` row in the `productdetails` table. Pretty sure you will have to do `FROM pdtemporary LEFT JOIN productdetails on pdtemporary.name = productdetails.name WHERE productdetails.name IS NULL`.  Try the `SELECT` by itself to confirm.

Comment: `INSERT 0 0` is not an error, it's a message telling you that the query was executed successfully and that your `SELECT` statement found no rows.

Comment: You certainly meant `name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM productdetails)`, not in the temporary table.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, You are right. Your solution worked. Thank you every one :) for the qiuck help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Adrian Klaver had the right solution. This code work well.

```
INSERT INTO productdetails (name, price, availability)

SELECT name, price, availability
                   
FROM pdtemporary LEFT JOIN productdetails on pdtemporary.name = productdetails.name WHERE productdetails.name IS NULL
```